# Get-Mailbox in PowerShell crashes because there's too many mailboxes

Tags: arrays, powershell, email, exchange-server, paging

I have a little problem, I want to get all the mailboxes and put them in a variable, which seems easy with

```
$mailboxes = Get-Mailbox
```

But there's too much mailboxes in our database (I think around 90k) and PowerShell crashes when I use this command. It works if I have like only 7500 mailboxes, I thought about using mailboxes paging, but how can I do something like:

```bsh
$allMailBoxes = @()
$mailboxes1 = Get-Mailbox -From 0 -To 10000
$mailboxes2 = Get-Mailbox -From 100001 -To 20000
$allMailBoxes += mailboxes1 += mailboxes2
```

Or is there any other solution I didn't think about? I need to store this data every week. I only need the numbers, the ones with the voice enterprise option, and the average mailbox size.

Current Code :

```html
        ## EXCHANGE 

        $allMailBoxes = Get-Mailbox -resultsize 7500
        $CountMailBoxes = $allMailBoxes.count

        $CountSharedMailBoxes = (Get-Mailbox -RecipientTypeDetails SharedMailbox -ResultSize:Unlimited).count
        
        #$CountSharedMailLists = voir flo
        $CountExchangeDatabases = (Get-MailboxDatabase).Count
        
        $MailBoxesStatistics = $allMailBoxes | Get-MailboxStatistics

        $tabMailBoxesSize = @()
        foreach ($Mailbox in $MailBoxesStatistics)
        {
            $MailboxSize = $Mailbox.TotalItemSize
            
            for($i = 0; $i -lt $MailboxSize.Length; $i++) {

                if ($MailboxSize[$i] -eq "(")
                {
                    $indexChevron = $i
                    ## formatted quota without the bytes : "1.9 GB <2,040,110,000 bytes>" becomes "1.9 GB"
                    $FormattedMailboxSize = Invoke-Expression ((($MailboxSize.Substring(0, $indexChevron-1)).replace(' ', '')))
                    $tabMailBoxesSize +=  $FormattedMailboxSize 
                }
            }
        }
        $tabMailBoxesSize = $tabmailboxessize | Measure-Object -Average | select Average
        $CountMailBoxesAverageSize = [math]::Round($tabmailboxesSize.Average/1GB, 2).toString() + " GB"
        Write-Output "Taille moyenne des BALs : $CountMailBoxesAverageSize"
```

Comment: I'm not an Exchange guy, so I can't really help here, but I can tell you that the last line is not going to work that way. You were probably trying to do something like `$allMailBoxes += $mailboxes1; $allMailBoxes += $mailboxes2`.

Comment: If you look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/mailboxes/get-mailbox?view=exchange-ps) you will find that the default `ResultSize` is 1000 so to get every mailbox you're already modifying that. In addition you will see that there is no paging for the cmdlet. What's your actual goal with that data? Otherwise you will need to find some property you can use to get your users partitioned. Maybe the name (aa-bb-cc) or the exchange database they "reside" in.

Comment: did you tried`Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited` still stuck?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers yeah thats what I meant sorry :)

Comment: @Seth Yeah thats what I figured out. I want to get the numbers of mailboxes, then the ones who have the option with voice enterprise, then get the average mail box size. I think that u're right i'll try to get with some alphabetic group search or something =/

Comment: @Avshalom yes it's this command that is stuck

Comment: What are you doing with this information. Why do you need to store it? You should be able to use the pipeline more efficiently or filter _before_ you store it. You might be able to query by mailbox database to reduce the result set into more manageable chunks.

Comment: @Matt its for reporting, I need to store these datas every week. I only need the numbers, the ones with the voice enterprise option, and the average mailbox size. I use the filter after storing it cause else I would have to search the 100k boxes three times instead of once

Comment: You might be able to get a user list (even limited to enterprise) using [Get-ExchangeServerAccessLicenseUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/organization/get-exchangeserveraccesslicenseuser?view=exchange-ps) depending on what you mean by enterprise in your context. As it's not fetching the whole mailbox it might be faster.

Comment: It's a property,  `$CountSkypeUsersWithVoiceEnterprise = ($allskypeusers | where {$_.EnterpriseVoiceEnabled -eq $true}).count`

Comment: How do you currently get the size? This is not stored in `Get-Mailbox` but `Get-MailboxStatistics`. Which totals do you need? Average for all? Just the voice? Total count and average of voice?

Comment: @Matt I'll update my code in the OP. It seems long and complex but necessary because totalItemSize.value doesnt work for me.. so I had to convert the string twice